# Advantages and disadvantages for Hp gas and indane gas

Tags: india

I'm in bangalore city in India. I wish to take a new gas connection. I wish to know the advantages and disadvantages for Hp gas and indane gas. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Advantages and disadvantages of fuels is definitely offtopic since it has nothing to do with personal finance per se.

Answer (score 1):

Indane Gas Does not have a centralised database to check how many connections are there on a particular house, which makes it easy to take 2 connection on same house.
Indane Gas in implementing Centralised database but this will take 1-2 year.

Whearas with HP Gas you can trasfer your connection easily to a different city if needed.
Even Bharat Gas has centralised system implemented.You can Book a Refill with just a text message with Bharat Gas.I'm not sure if other's have this facility.

Comming back to "Customer Service" Every distributor vary from City to City. It is higly personal to every City and location.